# Export views result as json, xml, csv etc?

Tags: views, 8, migrations

In Drupal 7 we had

- https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export
- https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource

Can Migrate in Drupal 8 replace these, for example to export view results with Migrate as JSON, CSV, etc?

Comment: migrate only imports not export.

Comment: You can you https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export for Drupal 8 as well. I am using this in my projects and its working fine.

Answer (score 8):

There are some options to export Views data in CSV format in Drupal 8

1. [Views Data Export Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of
>   data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered
>   progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support
>   exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV Microsoft
> - XLS (or really simple HTML understood by Excel)
> - Microsoft DOC
> - Basic TXT

2. [VBO Export Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/vbo_export) it adds CSV export feature for Views Bulk Operations  Moule

> The module adds 2 new Views Bulk Operations actions: Export to csv and export to Excel.

3.[CSV Serialization Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/csv_serialization)

This module provides a CSV encoder for the Drupal 8 Serialization API. This enables the CSV format to be used for data input and output in various circumstances. For example:

> Drupal 8's REST module can accept or return data in CSV format Views
>   can output CSV data via a 'REST Export' view Module developers may
>   leverage CSV as a format when using the Serialization API